# How to hide custom actions for anonymous users in the Mediawiki actions dropdown menu?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

In this picture [image: mediawiki dropdown], I want to hide the "Crypto sign" button for anonymous users.

I have tried various methods such as

- Setting `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['mycustomaction'] = false;` according to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights
- Define `getRestriction` method of my custom action which returns e.g. `upload`
- Define `doesWrites` method of my custom action which returns `true`

What is the correct way of doing this? I have looked at MediaWiki source code for e.g. `DeleteAction.php`, but can't find any clue.

Comment: How did you add that action?

Comment: @Tgr I added by specifying the custom action in extension.json. Though I have solved the problem by asking folks in MediaWiki IRC. I will post an answer here soon.

Comment: Well, no, that's added in the SkinTemplateNavigation hook. Just adding it to the list of actions doesn't make it show up in the dropdown. In that case, the hook is the right place to conditionally not add it, as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My extension is based on https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-examples. And my solution is to modify the hooks that adds the action, https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-examples/blob/f9c26110ca265c9298d436cd79a85935ad148ee1/includes/Hooks.php#L111 to do a permission check:

```
if ( !$this->permissionManager->userCan( 'edit', $skin->getUser(), $skin->getTitle() ) ) {
    return;
}
```